# Anaconda Tensorflow- ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to work on a ML model and install libraries such as tensorflow. I am doing this using Anaconda prompt and want to work on Jupyter Notebook.

```
python --version
Python 3.7.2
```

conda create -n venv python=3.7.2

Since I am using python 3. version I install tensorflow at this:

```
   pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Then I go to python interpreter to test module:

```
  import tensorflow as tf
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\shankar.ts\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\shankar.ts\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, 
    in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     File "C:\Users\shankar.ts\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", 
      line 40, in <module>
     from tensorflow.python.eager import context
    File "C:\Users\shankar.ts\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
      from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
     File "C:\Users\shankar.ts\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
      from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
    File "C:\Users\shankar.ts\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
      raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\shankar.ts\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site- 
     packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * 
     ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried downgrading my tensorflow version to 2.0.0 based on recommendations and I get:
Version not found

I would like to know what the issue is and how I must fix it.Also how I can check this and run it on Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 0):

Conda has its [own binaries](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow) and it is recommended to install python modules from conda source with conda install:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Create new environment and install all modules you need with conda install (e.g. [Jupyter](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/jupyter) )